# i just add firebase and it giving me error

Tags: java

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller
>   than version 16 declared in library
>   [com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4]
>   C:\Users\smsst.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\52cd5080d63c0547cae05690267d3335\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 14    Suggestion:
>   use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,         or increase
>   this project's minSdk version to at least 16,         or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display" to
>   force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Answer (score 1):

Your project has mininum Sdk Version 14, and to use Firebase, you must set minimum version to at least 16.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` change this line

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>`

to

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>`